# Modular design using AngularJS and UI-route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new in angularjs (I come from Java, Python, Objective-c) and I'm trying to achieve a modular design.
But I don't see how app.js can "import"other modules and then how controllers import other controllers and keep them in separate files.

This is what I want:

```
/app

     /img -- application level images
     /css -- application level css
     /js

     app.js -- the main app module
     /modules
         /login
             /js
                 controllers.js --controllers for login module
                 directives.js --directives for login module

             /views -- views for login module
             /css
             /img
             loginModule.js -- Main login module definition

         /comment
             /js
                 controllers.js --controllers for login module
                 directives.js --directives for login module

             /views -- views for comment module
             /css
             /img
             commentModule.js -- Main comment module definition

     ...

     ...

     index.html
```

Comment: i strongly advice you to read this https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide and https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y021. In the second link you can see better. What i usually do is combine functionality in an angular module and then i import that module in my main module (which usually is the app). When you import a module all the services controllers etc, of that module, will be available into the application.

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide as complete style guide and https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules for modularity in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import other `modules` by making them a dependence.

In your case, it would probably be something like this.

```
angular.module("app.module", ["login.module", "comment.module"]);
```

You could also group '***core***' functionalities into a module like `core.module`

```
angular.module("core.module", ["login.module", "comment.module"]);
```

Then make `app.module` depend on this module.

```
angular.module("app.module", ["core.module", "ui.router"]);
```

Hope that helps.

You reference your file in the `index.html` like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    // HTML code here

    // angular libraries and other vendor libaries

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<path to each module>"></script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I import each js module file on index.html ?

Comment: @Ricardo You'll need to provide the `<script type="text/javascript" src="..path to script file"></script>` in the correct order so your app module should be the last one because it depends on the other two in your `index.html`